# how to put legend title at left?

Tags: matplotlib

The following code creates a legend with a title.

```
from pylab import *
plt.plot([1,2],[2,3],label='sdfsdf')
legend(title='s')
```

[image: output picture here]

's' is located at the center of the legend.
I wonder how to put 's' to the left side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest option would probably be to add a lot of whitespace behind the title

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2],[2,3],label='sdfsdf')
plt.legend(title='s                ')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The drawback of this is of course that the amount of whitespace depends on the legend size.

The other option is therefore to change the alignment within the legend, using `._legend_box.align`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2],[2,3],label='sdfsdf')
leg = plt.legend(title='s')
leg._legend_box.align = "left"

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this is the aligment of all the legend entries, as there is unfortunately no way to align the title independently. In most cases it will not matter, but one has to be aware of that if unforeseen issues arise with more complex legends (multicolumn etc.).

Comment: As of version 3.6 there's an alignment argument that solves this (see 
Avi Vajpeyi's answer)

Answer (score 1):

### `matplotlib<3.6`

As mentioned by @importanceofbeingernest, with `matplotlib<3.6`, you would have to do smth like the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
plt.style.use("default")
plt.figure(figsize=(4,2))
plt.plot([1,2],[2,3],label=f'Matplot version {matplotlib.__version__}')
l = plt.legend(title='Some Title', loc='upper left')
l._legend_box.align='left'
plt.show()
```

[image: img1]

### `matplotlib==3.6` (possibly also for future versions)

A nifty `alignment` kwarg has been added. See [PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/23140) and [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.6.0/api/legend_api.html?highlight=legend#module-matplotlib.legend).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
plt.style.use("default")
plt.figure(figsize=(4,2))
plt.plot([1,2],[2,3],label=f'Matplot version {matplotlib.__version__}')
plt.legend(title='Some Title', loc='upper left', alignment='left')
plt.show()
```

[image: img2]

([Note lack of `alignment` kwarg in v3.4.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/api/legend_api.html?highlight=legend#module-matplotlib.legend))